VS Code folding is out of sync for a large JSON file. How to fix?
When I edit large files (20k+ lines with a lot of objects) sometimes folding can break totally and fold not the lines that it should and not where it should be
I attached few screenshots here for clarity and highlighted with squares the areas that will be folded when the button is pressed. Red highlighting has a folding error, the green one is ok.
It's actually folding the wrong things in the wrong places.
I increased editor.foldingMaximumRegions up to 50k and json.maxItemsComputed to 1mil, set editor.largeFileOptimization to true/false but it didn't change anything. Also i tried to search any similar problems but unfortunately didn't find any (unless that issue on vsc github)
So how can I solve this problem? I don't care about performance, my computer is pretty good. Any ways to fix it please

The problem was solved when I turned off and then turned on folding in vsc json settings file (“editor.folding”: false then “editor.folding”: true)
Apparently it was caching the sections that are folded somewhere. I had previously cleared the cache, but not where it needed to be
I hope this will help someone

what do you mean by "but not where it needed to be"? what did you do to supposedly "clear the cache"?

VSC cache folders are located in AppData/Roaming/Code. I deleted the contents of Cache and CachedData folders there. Maybe they were right cache folders. I didn't restart vsc after deleting them, maybe it was needed.
Anyway, swapping the editor.folding value is obviously faster and easier than cleaning the cache and restarting vsc. Although this is not a complete solution to the problem, but problem occurs not often and fixed literally in 5 seconds it is ok.
I will update my answer if I find a normal solution to fully prevent this folding issue.
